# Apply VCR OSD MONO With CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a website, and I want to apply the VCR OSD MONO font. Here is what I have tried:

```
h1 {
  background-image: url("rainbow.png");
  font:VCR;
}
@font-face {
        font-family: VCR;
        src: url(VCR OSD MONO.ttf);
}
```

Does any one know how to apply VCR OSD MONO.ttf to my website?
Also its not in code because for some reason stack says my code is formatted wrong?

Comment: Read this article at the part called "How to add custom fonts to your website using @font-face" https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-any-website

Comment: @warnakey its what I am looking for, but it does not say anything about a **ttf** file.

Comment: yes. It most certainly does say ttf...

Comment: @warnakey it says to convert it to a **otf** file but IDK how to do that...? is it like the situation with `.png` and `.ico`

Comment: @warnakey NVM I found a source from [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

Answer (score -1):

Do not uses spaces on your file names ! But don’t worry I made this mistake too when I first started. Prefer dashes or underscores when you name a file.

But if you really want to use spaces (which is a really bad practice by the way) learn that what we call spaces are in fact written by the computer like this "%20" or this "+", but it is being shown to you ass a white space like this " ".

So rename your file like this
VCR-OSD-MONO.ttf and don’t forget to rewrite your css code.

Good luck !

One more thing : web browsers prefer .woff or .woff2 files for external fonts.

Edit: And yes stack overflow was correct !